# MySQLi connect withtout specifying a database

Tags: php, database, pdo, mysqli

I am using many database and I would like to know if its possible to connect with mysqli and specify the database after : example

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$req = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = '1' ");
```

Would become

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password");
$req = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE id = '1' ");
```

I could add `$mysqli->select_db("database");` but if there is a way to use the query above, I'd like to know how to do. Thank you !

Comment: Waouh thank you for you help ! I didn't even think about that !

Comment: The text in the manual `dbname If provided will specify the default database to be used when performing queries.` let's one assume it's optional. Just try it. And yes, MySQL handles the format `database.table`

Answer (score 4):

Yes the method is quite simple actually, 
just do

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password");
$res = $mysqli->query("SHOW DATABASES");

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo ($results, $row['Database'] . "\n");
}
```